# C# parse nested object return null

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table named `Bah` with a pointer to another table called `man`
something like this:

`Bah` row:

```
id | name |    manId 
-----------------------
1  |  me  | Axlk9879nkj
```

I have a parse query:

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Bah");
query.Include("manId");
IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();
```

but in the result I have nulls in my `man` property.

Comment: are the results for the other property `null` as well?

Comment: I have no idea what library you are using, but you should probably write  `query.Include("man")`, not `query.Include("manId")`.

Comment: I'm using the parse apk. the man is my Users table